# EntityFramework: Model 1:0..1 relationship with fluent api + conventions

Tags: entity-framework

I have the following classes generated from an edmx model:

```
public partial class A
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual B B { get; set; }
}
public partial class B
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual A A { get; set; }
}
```

The existing db doesn't use the EF default which expects A.Id to be the primary key of table B:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[B] (
    [Id]    INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[A] (
    [Id]  INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [BId] INT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [fk] FOREIGN KEY ([BId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[B] ([Id])
);
```

With an edmx model, I can explicitly configure the multiplicity of each end, but I haven't found how to get the equivalent model using the fluent-api. When I do something like the following and generate a new db, the foreign key gets placed in table A instead of table B.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<A>().HasOptional(a => a.B).WithRequired(b => b.A);
```

I'm guessing I need to use a convention, but so far I've been unable to get the desired output.

**UPDATE:**

The closest solution I've found so far is to use the following which generates the correct SQL in the db:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<A>()
    .HasOptional(a => a.B)
    .WithOptionalDependent(b => b.A)
    .Map(c => c.MapKey("BId"));
```

However, it's conceptually modeled as a 0..1:0..1 relationship and I haven't found how to set a CASCADE delete rule that deletes B when A is deleted.

Comment: EF does not support such bidirectional relationship. For more info, see [Associations in EF Code First: Part 5 – One-to-One Foreign Key Associations](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-5-one-to-one-foreign-key-associations)

Comment: @IvanStoev As far as I can tell, this works without any problems using database first + edmx modeling. I'm just trying to switch it to database first + code without modifying the existing (working) db schema & generated classes. Both scenarios reference EntityFramework.dll & EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll, right? Does the edmx modeling use non-public functionality to enable the model customizations?

Comment: AFAIK there are some edmx features not supported by Code First, can't say if this is one of those. All I can say from my experience is that all from the linked series apply.

Comment: This fluent mapping should work as expected, i.e. a PK/FK in table B. Are you sure you're not mixing up the entities/tables? The required entity (`A`) is always the first to be created --because the optional entity (`B`) refers to it-- so it should generate the shared primary key value.

Comment: @GertArnold He doesn't want SPK though, but FK one-to-one association. Which means he needs to remove `public virtual A A { get; set; }` from `B` and use `modelBuilder.Entity<A>().HasOptional(a => a.B).WithMany();`

Comment: Ah, I guess that's right. I was responding to the last part of the question, the FK in `A` can't be right. It's true that an edmx allows more model tweaks than code-first, because it is able to change the conceptual model in ways the fluent API (or data annotations) don't expose. I assume something like that is going on here.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to find a direct solution, but using the following code seems to meet my requirements of preserving the existing schema and creating a conceptual model that has the same multiplicities & delete behaviors as my original edmx model.

I'd still be interested in any solutions that don't require updating the conceptual model during the post-processing IStoreModelConvention.

```
    {
        var overridesConvention = new OverrideAssociationsConvention();
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Add(overridesConvention);
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Add(new OverrideMultiplictyConvention(overridesConvention));
    }

    private class OverrideAssociationsConvention : IConceptualModelConvention<AssociationType>
    {
      ...
        public List<AssociationEndMember> MultiplicityOverrides { get; } = new List<AssociationEndMember>();
        public void Apply(AssociationType item, DbModel model)
        {
            if (multiplicityOverrides.Contains(item.Name))
            {
                // Defer actually updating the multiplicity until the store model is generated
                // so that foreign keys are placed in the desired tables.
                MultiplicityOverrides.Add(item.AssociationEndMembers.Last());
            }

            if (cascadeOverrides.Contains(item.Name))
            {
                item.AssociationEndMembers.Last().DeleteBehavior = OperationAction.Cascade;
            }
        }
    }

    private class OverrideMultiplictyConvention : IStoreModelConvention<EdmModel>
    {
        private readonly OverrideAssociationsConvention overrides;
        public OverrideMultiplictyConvention(OverrideAssociationsConvention overrides)
        {
            this.overrides = overrides;
        }

        public void Apply(EdmModel item, DbModel model)
        {
            overrides.MultiplicityOverrides.ForEach(o => o.RelationshipMultiplicity = RelationshipMultiplicity.One);
        }
    }
```