# UniDirectional 1-1 relationship in Entity Framework with Fluent API

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, ef-fluent-api

I'm working with an existing database, so I cannot change it. I have the following classes

```
public class SurveyQuestion
{
    public int SurveyQuestionId
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public string Questionu
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public virtual SurveyAnswer Answer
    {
        get; set;
    };
}

public class SurveyAnswer
{
    public int SurveyAnswerId
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public int SurveyQuestionId
    {
         get; set;
    }

    public string AnswerText
    {
        get; set;
    }
}
```

How do I set this up the Relationship between SurveyQuestion and SurveyAnswer with the Fluent API. As I have it now, I keep getting relationship errors. I know that if this was a one-many relationship, this would be automatic and work.

Again, this is how the tables are in a database I cannot change.

Comment: Same as this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/40616171/861716

Comment: It basically is. That one deals with BiDirectional, while this is unidirectional. I have not found any solutions offered in that question that work.